# cs50 implicit declaration of function 'get_int' is invalid in C99 in mario

Tags: c, cs50

I have started the mario problem set from cs50 2018 and have only written the first part to get the integer from the user. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
int n;

do {
    n = get_int("Number of rows: ");
}
    while (n < 0 || n > 23);
}
```

The error that is generating is this:

```
mario.c:9:9: error: implicit declaration of function 'get_int' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    n = get_int("Number of rows: ");
        ^
1 error generated.
```

My understanding is that this error usually means you have not included the correct library for the function, but I have included the CS50 library. Could anyone help?

N.B. My workspace is a couple of years old and I believe the CS50 library has been updated in this time. Is this causing the issue? I cannot create a new Harvard CS50 workspace because I already have an existing workspace and I am not a premium member.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: It's declared as `int get_int(void);` if my googling amounts to anything

Comment: Also new in the last couple of years is https://cs50.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Just to nitpick about terminology: A library might have one or more header files associated with it, but the header files itself (like e.g `<c50.h>`) are not the library itself.  Unless it's a [*header only* library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header-only), which the CS50 library isn't, and those are in general very uncommon in the C world.

Comment: As for the error you get, in older versions of C it was allowed to have undeclared function, and the compiler would deduce (often) what the function prototype was. Since the C99 standard implicit declarations have been disallowed. If the function is a part of the CS50 library (which it should be IIRC) then it should have been declared by the `<cs50.h>` header file. Unless you include the wrong header file, or a very old one where the `get_int` functions isn't declared. Is the error you get the *only* error you have? There's no *warnings*?

Comment: Make sure you're using a recent version of `<cs50.h>`.  There was a revision a year (or two or three) ago which added `get_int()`  — and deprecated `GetInt()` which had been used before.  Since you're including a `cs50.h` header but not getting the declaration, the header is in some sense incomplete.  If it's empty, that's a problem; if it's the old version, that's a problem; otherwise, it isn't yet obvious what the trouble is.  You may be able to use `grep get_int /usr/local/include/cs50.h` (for whichever directory your `cs50.h` is installed int).

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. I think you were right Jonathan, I deleted my cloud 9 account and created a new one and it is all working now!

Comment: As you might be able to tell I am a complete noob at this so apologies if some of what I say doesn’t make sense

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using a recent version of `cs50.h`. There was a revision a year (or two or three) ago which added `get_int()` — and deprecated `GetInt()` which had been used before. Since you're including a `cs50.h` header but not getting the declaration, the header is in some sense incomplete. If it's empty, that's a problem; if it's the old version, that's a problem; otherwise, it isn't yet obvious what the trouble is. You may be able to use `grep get_int /usr/local/include/cs50.h` (for whichever directory your `cs50.h` is installed in). – Jonathan Leffler 12 hours ago